# Problems scaling SpringWebFlow application on heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, primefaces, spring-webflow

So here is my problem. I'm developing a SpringWebFlow based application on Heroku cloud and I seem to be missing something.

The app runs well on a single dyno, but when I scale it up to use multiple dynos it stops working (properly). I thought it's something to do with my code, but then I deployed a sample [SpringWebFlow app](http://webflowprimefaces.herokuapp.com/) (that can be found here: https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/webflow-primefaces-showcase) to check if the problem will manifest itself and it does. It's hard to describe, but in general flows seem to be malfunctioning i.e. you have to click several times on certain buttons to make them do what they're expected to do, sometimes pages refresh themselves etc. As if there was some problem with request/session handling. As soon as I go back to using a single dyno, everything works well, instantly.

As I'm new to both Spring and Heroku, is there something I should keep in mind and be aware of when scalling up to multiple dynos? And if so, how to make this sample app scale up well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved my own issue. It was session management issue. Memcached addon solved it.